# Preg_Replace not working on French Character - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I've searched for a while so hopefully this is not a question that is asked many times already.

I'm trying to program on php a script that would remove stop words from a string, and then explode it in an array of words. The stop words could be in English or French.

Currently the following is not working for me as it doesn't remove French characters:

```
$needles=array(
'/\bil\b/i', 
'/\bla\b/i', 
'/\ble\b/i', 
'/\b'. htmlentities('à') .'\b/i'
);
print_r($needles);

$result=preg_replace($needles, "", htmlentities("il y à trois personne dans la salle à manger"));
print_r($result);
```

The output removes everything but not the french character: à

Comment: Why do you use `htmlentities()` here?

Comment: If you apply [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) on both input and regex pattern beforehand, then it'll become `&a…;` → where the word `\b` boundary won't match on either end.

Comment: Indeed, `htmlentities()` must be used (if needed) only before including text in html. If you need to edit the string before don't use it.

Comment: Have to say I was confused since the text I've receive have these accents, thought the htmlentities would allow me to at least normalize everything to UTF 8. What is to do here, even replace with &agrave; does not remove the accented character from string.

Comment: Arghh! UTF8 is not what you think.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been noted in the comments, `htmlentities('à')` will give you `[3] => /\b&agrave;\b/i`. [It won't match your letter](https://regex101.com/r/kA5vR6/3).

Instead, use the `à` with `u` flag to enable Unicode in the pattern:

```
'/\bà\b/iu'
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kA5vR6/5)

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/itX07L):

```
<?php
$needles=array(
'/\bil\b/i', 
'/\bla\b/i', 
'/\ble\b/i', 
'/\bà\b/iu'
);
print_r($needles);

$result=preg_replace($needles, "", "il y à trois personne dans la salle à manger");
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
y  trois personne dans  salle  manger
```

Comment: oh wow thanks for the help. This fixes my issue, and I got a slight better understanding about when to use htmlentities.